# Why does android create a file when I delete a folder?

Tags: android, file, directory

I am saving image file in specified folder using the following code:-

```
private void captureImage(int usertype, String id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        mFileURI = getOutputMediaFileUri(usertype, id);

        if(mFileURI!=null)
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mFileURI);
        else{
            new AlertDialog.Builder(WorkspaceActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Cannot create folder")
                .setMessage("Unable to create directory please try later.")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                        // continue with delete
                    }
                 })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                 .show();
        }

        if(mFileURI!=null){
        // start the image capture Intent
            if (usertype == PIC_OF_TEAM) {
                startActivityForResult(intent,
                    CAMERA_CAPTURE_TEAM_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
            } else if (usertype == PIC_OF_STUDENT) {
                startActivityForResult(intent,
                    CAMERA_CAPTURE_STUDENT_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
/*
 * returning image file
 */
private File getOutputMediaFile(int usertype, String id,
        String packagename) {

    String tempId               =   id;
    File mediaStorageDir        =   null;
    String userType             =   "";
    // External sdcard location
    if (usertype == PIC_OF_STUDENT) {

        String studentLocalPicUrl   =   AppConstants.STUDENT_PIC_LOCAL_URL;
        studentLocalPicUrl          =   studentLocalPicUrl.replace("/bibox/", "/bibox/"+mMentorID+"/");
        File file                   =   new File(studentLocalPicUrl);


        mediaStorageDir             =   new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),studentLocalPicUrl);

        userType                    =   AppConstants.PIC_STUDENT;
    } else if (usertype == PIC_OF_TEAM) {

        String teamLocalPicUrl  =   AppConstants.TEAM_PIC_LOCAL_URL;
        teamLocalPicUrl         =   teamLocalPicUrl.replace("/bibox/", "/bibox/"+mMentorID+"/");
        mediaStorageDir         =   new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                teamLocalPicUrl);
        userType    =   AppConstants.PIC_TEAM;
    }

    if (mediaStorageDir != null)
        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("MediaHelper", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

    // Create a media file name
    File mediaFile      =   null;
    String imagePath    =   mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + tempId+ ".jpg";
    mediaFile           =   new File(imagePath);
    if(mediaFile.exists()){ 
        //If file already exists do this.
        do{
            imagePath           =   imagePath.replace(tempId, tempId+"_"+generateRandomNo());
            mediaFile           =   new File(imagePath);
        }while(mediaFile.exists());
    }

    //Assign the id, image path, user type
    //So that we can use it for further use in the database.
    mId         =   id;
    mMediaPath  =   imagePath;
    mUserType   =   userType;

    return mediaFile;
}


public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int usertype, String id) {

        File outputMediaFile    = getOutputMediaFile(usertype, id, getPackageName());

        if(outputMediaFile==null)
            return null;

        return Uri.fromFile(outputMediaFile);
    }
```

The value of the constant is :-

```
public static String STUDENT_PIC_LOCAL_URL = "/bibox/img/student";
```

The problem is that after taking the image, if I delete the folder mMentorId, then there is a junk file created of 0bytes, the screen shot of the file is shown below, I have tried searching a lot about this, but nothing is fruitfull.

[image: file created on deletion of folder]

Comment: `if I delete the folder mMentorId, then there is a junk file created`. So it is not there before you delete that folder? Then what has it to do with your code as you are not deleting directories? Further you did not tell the value of `TEAM_PIC_LOCAL_URL`. And we cannot see the value of variable `mMentorId`.

Comment: mMentorId has normal string values, TEAM_PIC_LOCAL_URL values will not effect the execution of the code for this case. This case mMentorId has value "pawan".

Comment: You should of course have told right away that mMentirId had value pawan. So you created pawan yourself. Is it a file with size 0 or an empty directory? You did not clear up the confusion when pawan was created. I asked if it was created only after you trying to delete directories. Please answer. If TEAM_PIC_LOCAL_URL is not involved in the problem then you should not have posted that code.

Comment: I copied the whole function, so TEAM_PIC_LOCAL_URL was involved in that, it is just that I didnt take the pain to filter it out, and pawan(mMentorId) is a folder created by me, the problem is that when I delete the folder, there is a file(of size 0KB) that is created, this shouldnot have happened.

Comment: You should of course have taken the pain to filter it out. According the rules. And now it's time you tell how you are deleting a folder with the name pawan which results in an empty file with the name pawan. Why do you let us guess?

Comment: I am deleting it manually, but however, regardless of whether it is deleted manually or through code, it results in a 0KB file of the same name as mMentorId.

Comment: Sorry, i can not help you as you keep being vague, not exact.

Comment: Ok, thanks, let use see whether others can help :)